# Merging of tables in R based on primary key which has different number(count) of values and where other columns have different values

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, data.table

I have a data table " table 1" which is mentioned below:

```
table1 <- read.table(text=" origin dest  airline  market      share
  XYZ   ABC     DL      XYZ-ABC      100%
  QWE   WER     AA      QWE-WER       20%
  QWE   WER     DL      QWE-WER       40% 
  QWE   WER     UA      QWE-WER       40%
  UYT   WER     EV      UYT-WER      100%",
  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I have another table "table 2" which is :

```
table2 <- read.table(text="city1 city2  airline  market      share
  XYZ   ABC     DL      XYZ-ABC      100%
  QWE   WER     AS      QWE-WER       60%
  QWE   WER     OH      QWE-WER       40% 
  TRE   BNJ     2O      TRE-BNJ      100%
  UYT   WER     DL      UYT-WER       20%
  UYT   WER     AA      UYT-WER       80%", 
  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I would like to compare the tables and get a table where the "market" of both table matches as shown below:

```
 origin dest airline market    share city1 city2  airline  market      share
  XYZ   ABC     DL   XYZ-ABC   100%  XYZ   ABC     DL      XYZ-ABC     100%
  QWE   WER     AA   QWE-WER   20%   QWE   WER     AS      QWE-WER      60%
  QWE   WER     DL   QWE-WER   40%   QWE   WER     OH      QWE-WER      40%
  QWE   WER     UA   QWE-WER   40%   Na    Na      Na      Na            na 
  UYT   WER     EV  UYT-WER  100 %  UYT   WER     DL      UYT-WER       20 %                                  
   Na   Na      Na   Na        Na   UYT   WER     AA      UYT-WER       80 %
```

The na(s) can be blank too.

I did a join :

```
comparison <- merge( table1,table2, by.x = c("market"), by.y =c("market"))
```

However I got a table like:

```
market  origin  dest airline.x  share.x city1   city2 airline.y share.y
QWE-WER  QWE        WER  AA          20%    QWE     WER       AS    60%
QWE-WER  QWE        WER  AA          20%    QWE     WER       OH    40%
QWE-WER  QWE        WER  DL          40%    QWE     WER       AS    60%
QWE-WER  QWE        WER  DL          40%    QWE     WER       OH    40%
QWE-WER  QWE        WER  UA          40%    QWE     WER       AS    60%
QWE-WER  QWE        WER  UA          40%    QWE     WER       OH    40%
UYT-WER  UYT        WER  EV         100%    UYT     WER       DL    20%
UYT-WER  UYT        WER  EV         100%    UYT     WER       AA    80%
XYZ-ABC  XYZ        ABC  DL         100%    XYZ     ABC       DL    100%
```

Although the column names can be changed, this table is not convenient to do further analysis. It would be good if all the markets  are in the same line .

Can anyone suggest a better way to join or combine the tables?

Comment: Can you more carefully describe your join rules? You basically also want to match on a "market index" column so that the first, second, third, row from each market matches up to each other?

Comment: "All the markets are in the same line" do you mean you want one row per market? If that's the case, you need to tell us how you want to aggregate the different parameters like `airline.x` and `share.x`

Comment: @MrFlick yes.. basically I want to match on a "market index and compare  in two tables what are airlines serving those markets. However as you can see in the  final output (3rd table) , the x table ( airline.x etc) is having duplicate rows in QWE-WER. I expected 3 but got 6.  I would like to get a table as mentioned in 3rd table of description.

Comment: @Mako212  "All the markets are in the same line" - as you can see duplicate rows per market in x table( airline.x ) - where ever there are multiple airlines in the martket, I would like to get one line per market per airline as shown in the 3rd table of description.

Comment: You aggregate lines three and four of the final table in your expected output into a single row, when `airline.y` is different. Do you not care about `airline.y`?

Comment: Instead of a join shouldn't this not be rather combined via `rbind` and then calculate all the following steps based on this new data.table? I would say the primary ID is the combination of market and airline, or?